# XmlDocument - listar todos elementos?

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

Eu tenho um código `XML` semelhante a este :

```
<document>
   <elemento>

   </elemento>
</document>
```

e o seguinte código C#: (`x` é um  XmlDocument)

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.ChildNodes.Count; i ++)
{
    var element = x.ChildNodes[i];
    Console.WriteLine("Elemento: " + element.Name);
}
```

Acontece que ele só lista o primeiro filho do elemento, no caso `document` e não lista os filhos do `document`. Como eu posso listar todos elementos do código `XML`, incluindo filhos dos filhos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar XPath para selecionar todos os nós:

```
var todosOsNos = x.SelectNodes("//*");
for (int i = 0; i < todosOsNos.Count; i++)
{
    var element = todosOsNos[i];
    Console.WriteLine("Elemento: " + element.Name);
}
```

A expressão `//*` quer dizer o seguinte:

- `//` significa que se deve buscar um elemento em qualquer nível da árvore
- `*` significa que qualquer elemento serve (ou seja, não estamos especificando um filtro de elemento)

Em conjunto isso significa: pegue os elementos, sejam quais forem, em qualquer nível da árvore.